# How do you answer the Opt-In question when applying for a 10DLC (10 digit long code) for sending SMS messages in the United States?

Tags: sms, twilio

In the United States, you [now have to apply for a 10DLC](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/4405850570267-Nonprofit-and-Government-Guide-to-A2P-10DLC-Text-Messaging#h_01FE4NT7XZMRQR9Y4BMEA7NNX7) (10 digit long code) in order to send text messages from CiviCRM to your contacts.

I recently tried to follow all the instructions to register and I got through all of it except the last step: Registering a campaign.

I was rejected due to: "The campaign submission has been reviewed and it was rejected because of provided Opt-in information"

For the Opt In section of the form I wrote: "End users opt in by providing their cell phone number via an optional field on their membership form that lets them know they will receive text message reminders if they provide their number."

Apparently that is not good enogh. The [approval requirements](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/11847054539547-A2P-10DLC-Campaign-Approval-Requirements) state:

```
Confirmation message must be delivered immediately after the Consumer opts into the program. 
Message must contain
    Program or product description
    Customer care contact information
    Opt-out instructions
    Product quantity or recurring messages program disclosure
    “Message and data rates may apply” disclosure
```

[In another spot](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30896), it says you have to include a link to your sign up page that demonstrates the opt in procedure and includes a link to your privacy policy and your terms of service.

I'm curious to know if anyone else has successfully applied for a 10DLC and if so what you put in your application for the Opt in procedure? It seems we would have to set up a scheduled reminder that can trigger on sign ups and send an SMS to be fully in compliance.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

@gutyn - yes! After a lot of trial and error I have received approval. Here is what finally worked:

First, write a privacy policy and publish it on your web site.

Then create a CiviCRM profile form that includes first name, last name, mobile phone number, and the "Do NOT SMS" privacy field check box containing the label: Do NOT send me SMS messages (unchecked by default) and the post field help: If you do NOT want to received SMS messages check this box. If you leave this box UNCHECKED and you provide your cell phone number than you authorize ORGANIZATION XYZ to send SMS announcements about ORGANIZATION XYZ. Messaging data rates may apply. You can opt out by sending STOP at any time.

Be sure a link to your privacy policy is on the profile page (maybe in the footer).

Then, in the campaign application, provide answers along these lines:

- Description: This campaign sends reminders for upcoming educational webinars or membership meetings.
- Sending messages with embedded links?: Yes
- Sending messages with embedded phone numbers?: No
- Message Sample #1: Our webinar on XYZ is starting in 10 minutes and you are
  registered. You can join by following this link:
  https://example.net/123.
- Message Sample #2: Our annual membership meeting process is starting next month - please register by followingthis link: https://example.net/abc.
- How do end-users consent to receive messages?: End users opt-in by visiting [Link to your Profile] and adding their name and phone number and checking a box to agree to receive text messages from YOUR ORG. Opt in occurs after the form is filled out. See screenshot: LINK TO UPLOADED SCREEN SHOT.
- Opt-in Message: [No option to opt-in via text message is available.]